# Search table twice in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've come across this issue several times now and I am not sure how to solve it. I have a query that needs to access the same table twice to pick out two different persons: a consultant and the customer contact.

Consultant + Customer query looks like this

```
select 
    CRM7.contact.contact_id as CustomerID, 
    CRM7.contact.name + ' ' + CRM7.person.firstname + ' ' + CRM7.person.LASTNAME as CustomerName, 
    CRM7.person.firstname + ' ' + CRM7.person.lastname as ConsultantName,
    CRM7.udcontactsmall.long08 as WriteLic, 
    CRM7.udcontactsmall.long17 as ReadLic, 
    CRM7.udcontactsmall.long09 as HasMaint, 
    CRM7.udlist.name as BCVer 
from 
    CRM7.contact,
    CRM7.udcontactsmall 
left join 
    CRM7.associate on CRM7.udcontactsmall.long11 = CRM7.associate.associate_id 
left join 
    CRM7.person on CRM7.associate.person_id = CRM7.person.person_id 
left join 
    CRM7.udlist on CRM7.udcontactsmall.long07 = CRM7.udlist.UDList_id 
where 
    CRM7.contact.category_idx = '2' and
    CRM7.contact.userdef_id = CRM7.udcontactsmall.udcontactsmall_id
order by 
    CRM7.contact.name
```

And the one that gets the contact for each customer looks like this

```
SELECT  
    C.NAME+' Kontakt '+ P.FIRSTNAME+' '+P.LASTNAME AS CONTACT
FROM 
    CRM7.PERSON P
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    CRM7.CONTACT C ON P.CONTACT_ID = C.CONTACT_ID
WHERE 
    C.CATEGORY_IDX IN ('2','5') 
    AND P.RETIRED = 0  
ORDER BY 
    C.NAME, P.LASTNAME, P.FIRSTNAME
```

Dataset:

http://oi61.tinypic.com/2j66cjq.jpg

How do I get a query which returns both the consultant for the customer and the customer contact?

Comment: Don't put those right side table conditions in the WHERE clause if you really want a LEFT JOIN. (If you do, you get inner join behavior.) Move to ON clause to get true LEFT JOIN execution.

Comment: Curious as to why you store consultant and customer in the same table

Comment: @jarlh - As you can see, the where clause does not have any condition on the tables joined with a left join, so although your statement is true, it will not have any effect in this case.

Comment: You really need to stop using the old style join. The newer join syntax has been around for more than 25 years now. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins

Comment: And 3 and 4 part naming in the list of columns has been deprecated. You should use aliases in your query. It adds clarity and far less code.

Comment: External system not by choice im afraid.

Comment: WHERE C.CATEGORY_IDX in ('2','5')... Makes that LEFT JOIN an inner join.

Answer (score 0):

This should serve your purpose:

```
select 
    CRM7.contact.contact_id as CustomerID
    ,CRM7.contact.name+' '+CRM7.person.firstname+' '+CRM7.person.LASTNAME as CustomerName
    ,CRM7.person.firstname+' '+CRM7.person.lastname as ConsultantName
    ,CRM7.udcontactsmall.long08 as WriteLic
    ,CRM7.udcontactsmall.long17 as ReadLic
    ,CRM7.udcontactsmall.long09 as HasMaint
    ,CRM7.udlist.name as BCVer 
    ,C.NAME+' Kontakt '+ CRM7.person.FIRSTNAME+' '+ CRM7.person.LASTNAME AS CONTACT
from 
    CRM7.contact
    ,CRM7.udcontactsmall 
    left join CRM7.associate on CRM7.udcontactsmall.long11=CRM7.associate.associate_id 
    left join CRM7.person on CRM7.associate.person_id=CRM7.person.person_id 
    left join CRM7.udlist on CRM7.udcontactsmall.long07=CRM7.udlist.UDList_id 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT CONTACT_ID,NAME FROM CRM7.CONTACT WHERE CATEGORY_IDX in ('2','5') AND P.RETIRED=0) C ON CRM7.person.CONTACT_ID=C.CONTACT_ID
where 
    CRM7.contact.category_idx='2' 
    and CRM7.contact.userdef_id=CRM7.udcontactsmall.udcontactsmall_id 
order by 
    CRM7.contact.name
```

I have used a join on contact table from the second query and added it into the first one to get customer contacts:

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    (SELECT CONTACT_ID, NAME 
     FROM CRM7.CONTACT 
     WHERE CATEGORY_IDX IN ('2','5') AND P.RETIRED = 0) C ON CRM7.person.CONTACT_ID = C.CONTACT_ID
```

Comment: Hi do i not need the 

LEFT OUTER JOIN CRM7.CONTACT C ON P.CONTACT_ID=C.CONTACT_ID

Inside that Left outer join for that to work?

Comment: Yes i see now. It gives an error "Invalid column name 'Retired'-

Removing it ran the query and it gives null values.

Comment: Tried it like this

LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT CONTACT_ID,NAME FROM CRM7.CONTACT WHERE CATEGORY_IDX in ('2','5')) C ON CRM7.person.CONTACT_ID=C.CONTACT_ID

And 

CRM7.person.FIRSTNAME+' '+ CRM7.person.LASTNAME AS CONTACT

This gives me Consultants again

Comment: ok great. I see why the retired field gave an error. It belonged to Person which was not in the sub query.

Comment: In my mind it should work and i should recieve customers instead of Consultants but i just get the Consultants again. Is it because of CRM7.person.CONTACT_ID using the old values?

Comment: can you post the data set you get on running the query?

Comment: Edited with dataset. if i run the query suggested i get the ConsultName as Contact aswell